# What's the difference between Assert.AreNotEqual and Assert.AreNotSame?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing, assert

In C#, what's the difference between

```
Assert.AreNotEqual
```

and

```
Assert.AreNotSame
```

Comment: Adding two cents here: This is not a question about the C# language itself, but rather the implementation details of testing frameworks such as [MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.aspx) and [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php/index.php?p=comparisonAsserts&r=2.2).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Almost all the answers given here are correct, but it's probably worth giving an example:

```
public static string GetSecondWord(string text)
{
    // Yes, an appalling implementation...
    return text.Split(' ')[1];
}

string expected = "world";
string actual = GetSecondWord("hello world");

// Good: the two strings should be *equal* as they have the same contents
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

// Bad: the two string *references* won't be the same
Assert.AreSame(expected, actual);
```

`AreNotEqual` and `AreNotSame` are just inversions of `AreEqual` and `AreSame` of course.

EDIT: A rebuttal to the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543263/whats-the-difference-between-assert-arenotequal-and-assert-arenotsame/543337#543337)...

If you use `Assert.AreSame` with value types, they are boxed. In other words, it's equivalent to doing:

```
int firstNumber = 1;
int secondNumber = 1;
object boxedFirstNumber = firstNumber;
object boxedSecondNumber = secondNumber;

// There are overloads for AreEqual for various value types
// (assuming NUnit here)
Assert.AreEqual(firstNumber, secondNumber);

// ... but not for AreSame, as it's not intended for use with value types
Assert.AreSame(boxedFirstNumber, boxedSecondNumber);
```

Neither `firstNumber` nor `secondNumber` has an object value, because `int` is a value type. The reason the `AreSame` call will fail is because in .NET, boxing a value creates a new box each time. (In Java it sometimes doesn't - this has caught me out before.)

Basically you should *never* use `AreSame` when comparing value types. When you're comparing *reference* types, use `AreSame` if you want to check for identical references; use `AreEqual` to check for equivalence under `Equals`. EDIT: Note that there *are* situations where NUnit doesn't just use `Equals` directly; it has built-in support for collections, where the elements in the collections are tested for equality.

The claim in the answer that:

> Using the example above changing the
> int to string, AreSame and AreEqual
> will return the same value.

entirely depends on how the variables are initialized. If they use string literals, then yes, interning will take care of that. If, however, you use:

```
string firstString = 1.ToString();
string secondString = 1.ToString();
```

then `AreSame` and `AreEqual` will almost certainly *not* return the same value.

As for:

> The general rule of thumb is to use
> AreEqual on value types and AreSame on
> reference types.

I almost *never* want to check for reference identity. It's rarely useful to me. I want to check for *equivalence* which is what `AreEqual` checks for. (I'm not saying that `AreSame` shouldn't be there - it's a useful method, just far more rarely than `AreEqual`.)

Comment: Shouldn't AreSame be generic method with class constraint?

Comment: It would be now, if NUnit came out not caring about 1.1 support, I'm sure.

Comment: All this confusion raises the question: why not just have a single Assert method?

Comment: @Earwicker: Because you don't always want to check for the same thing.  Yes, there could be Assert(bool) - but that couldn't give as much information when you pass it false as AreEqual etc do.

Comment: Just a thought but how about Debug.Assert(() => x == y); i.e. pass a lambda of type Func<bool>. Then Assert can accept it as Expression<Func<bool>>, so if it fails it can turn it into a string to include it in the test log.

Comment: It's usually the values which are important, and the expression wouldn't show those.

Comment: Challenge accepted! http://incrediblejourneysintotheknown.blogspot.com/2009/02/displaying-nested-evaluation-tree-from.html

Comment: @Earwicker: Will take a closer look later. I doubt that you'll easily be able to *easily* do some of the nice things JUnit and NUnit can though, such as spotting that strings are different and doing a diff to make it easy to spot changes. Feasible I expect, but harder than having the extra method :)

Comment: Yes, I should probably try making it into a wrapper around NUnit and see which nice facilities can be reproduced practically.

Comment: You say "use AreEqual to check for equivalence under Equals.", but doesn't http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789818/c-assert-arenotequal-versus-equals demonstrate that `AreEquals` is _not_ quite the same as calling a `.Equals` function?

Answer (score 26):

Two things can be equal, but different objects. AreNotEqual checks the objects *values* via the equality test, while AreNotSame checks that they are not the same exact object.

It is obvious why we would want to test that things AreNotEqual (we care about the values being tested); what about AreNotSame? The usefulness of this in testing is found when you have passed references around and want to make sure that after your shuffling is done that two references are still the same object.

In a real world case, we use a lot of caching objects to mitigate round trips to the database. After an object has been handed off to the cache system, our unit tests ensure that in some cases we get back the same object (cache was valid) and in other cases we get back a *fresh* object (cache was invalidated). Note that AreNotEqual would not necessary suffice in this case. If the object had a new timestamp in the database, yet the *data* was not "different enough" to fail an equality test, AreNotEqual wouldn't notice that we refreshed the *object*.

Answer (score 20):

[AreNotSame](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.arenotsame.aspx) does reference comparison, whereas [AreNotEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.arenotequal.aspx) does an equality comparison.

Answer (score 8):

Assert.AreNotEqual asserts that two values are not equal to each other.

Assert.AreNotSame asserts that two variables do not point to the same object.

Example 1:

```
int i = 1;
int j = i;
// The values are equal:
Assert.AreEqual(i, j);
// Two value types do *not* represent the same object:
Assert.AreNotSame(i, j);
```

Example 2:

```
string s = "A";
string t = s;
// The values are equal:
Assert.AreEqual(s, t);
// Reference types *can* point to the same object:
Assert.AreSame(s, t);
```

Answer (score 7):

AreNotSame uses reference equality (`object.ReferenceEquals`) - i.e. are they the same actual instance of an object; AreNotEqual uses conceptual equality (`.Equals`) - i.e. are they *considered* equal.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it so that AreNotEqual checks for the case where two objects are not equal in terms of Equals() method, whereas AreNotSame checks for the case where the two object references are not the same. So if x and y are two objects which are equal in terms of Equals() but have been separately allocated, AreNotEqual() would trigger failing assertion but the other not.