# C# Assert.AreNotEqual versus Equals

Tags: c#, nunit, equals

While trying to verify to myself, that C# Equals for IEnumerables is a reference equals, I found something odd. With the following setup in NUnit

```
var a = (IEnumerable<string>)(new[] { "one", "two" });
var b = (IEnumerable<string>)(new[] { "one", "two" });
```

this test

```
Assert.IsFalse(a.Equals(b));
```

passes, while this test

```
Assert.AreNotEqual(a, b);
```

doesn't. Can anybody explain why?

Edit: Thanks for the answers. I just read the documentation for NUnit, and it says the same thing, that AreEqual and AreNotEqual with collections test for equality of each element of the collection. I guess I was stuck with the notion, that AreEqual and AreNotEqual was just using plain Equals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The call to `a.Equals(b)` returns `false` because a and b are not the same objects (though they are of course identical enumerations). The `Equals` method, unless overridden, automatically compares objects by their reference, which is what is happening in this case.

[`Assert.AreNotEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243457.aspx) is a bit more clever than this. It is designed for debugging purposes, unlike the `Equals` method, so it in fact compares the sequences yielded by the two enumerations, since it recognises `IEnumerable<T>` as a special type. You should also notice that it does other interesting things, such as returning `true` when the two parameters are numerically identical but of different value types (e.g. `short` and `long`).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't look at NUnit source code to see how NUnit guys coded AreNotEqual.
However, I can tell you how it's done for MbUnit that has the same behavior.

First in AssertNotEqual(a, b) checks if references are equal by executing code like this:

```
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(left, right))
        return true;
```

In your case it's going to fail.  Next it checks if the objects are IEnumerable type.  If they are, iterate through them and compare if the items are the same and in the same order.

However, in T type in IEnumerable is more complex than string or ValueType in MbUnit AssertNotEqaual(a, b) will not fail.

```
    var a = (IEnumerable<StringBuilder>)(new[] { new StringBuilder("one"), new StringBuilder("two") });
    var b = (IEnumerable<StringBuilder>)(new[] { new StringBuilder("one"), new StringBuilder("two") });

    Assert.IsFalse(a.Equals(b));  // Success
    Assert.AreNotEqual(a, b);     // Success
```