# Diff between Assert.AreEqual and Assert.AreSame?

Tags: c#, assert

What is the difference between **Assert.AreEqual** and **Assert.AreSame**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Assert.AreNotEqual and Assert.AreNotSame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543263/whats-the-difference-between-assert-arenotequal-and-assert-arenotsame)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It means that AreSame() checks that they are the exact same object - if reference indicate the same object in memory.

AreEqual() checks that objects has equal type and value. Equal objects can exist in two different places in memory.

Answer (score 78):

`Assert.AreEqual(a, b)` is the same as `Assert.IsTrue(Object.Equals(a, b))`

`Assert.AreSame(a, b)` is the same as `Assert.IsTrue(Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b))`

(the only reason I knew is I just figured it out myself a few hours ago today because I needed to do a `Assert.IsTrue(Object.ReferenceEquals(a,b))` and thought *"I wonder if there is a better way to do this")*