# Nunit Assert.AreEqual() fails when comparing two custom objects

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm working on a test for an interview and need to write a few classes that are then tested with `Assert` statements. There is one part where two objects are tested with `Assert.AreEqual()` immediately followed by a test with `Assert.AreNotSame` for the same two objects. My understanding is that the first test checks that two objects have the same values (a and b in my example) and the second test checks that they point two different objects in memory. However, the first `Assert` fails both in my example and in the program. Am I missing something about how those two `Assert` tests should work? How can they both pass?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public Foo(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
}
Foo a = new Foo();
a.a = 1;
a.b = 2;

Foo b = new Foo(1, 2);

Assert.AreEqual(a,b);//this fails
Assert.AreNotSame(a,b);
```

Comment: You need to implement an Equals override on Foo. Otherwise the default is reference equality.

Comment: @MikeZboray I'm just not sure if it's allowed but I can't think how else to make it pass.

Comment: What is the point of this test? Is it not to modify the code of Foo to make the test pass? You are the one with the test so you'll have provide more of the context for us.

Comment: @MikeZboray The instructions are very ambiguous (on purpose I believe) but the design of the classes is up to me - there's no templates provided.

Comment: this is the test https://www.alliancereservations.com/developer-test.html

Answer (score 3):

Both objects are not equal and not same since it is two different instances of the object.

If you override Equals method on the object than you can implement it in a way that you check if the properties of both objects are equal. If they are than the object is also equal. So your new class should look like this...

```
public class Foo
{
    public int a { get; set; }
    public int b { get; set; }

    public Foo(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return ((Foo)obj).a == this.a && ((Foo)obj).b == this.b;
    }
}
```

Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172782/diff-between-assert-areequal-and-assert-aresame) SO answer for further clarification...

Comment: This implementation can throw invalid cast and null reference exceptions. Exceptions are not expected from Equals/GetHashCode methods.

Comment: @taffer You missed the point in order to make your own point. Of course it can throw those two exception. This was just a show case of why his code is working the way it is working.