# Double comparison failing

Tags: vb.net, double

The comparison of double is giving me unexpected results. When I increase 0.0 of Epsilon I get an increased value, when I increase 25.0 of Epsilon I get exactly 25.0, not more. How can I increase 25.0 of the minimum double to trigger the comparison? And why is working with 0.0 and not with 25.0?

```
    <TestMethod()>
    Public Sub Test()
        Const epsilon As Double = Double.Epsilon
        Const zero As Double = 0.0
        Const zeroPlusEpsilon As Double = zero + epsilon
        Const twentyfive As Double = 25.0
        Const twentyfivePlusEpsilon As Double = twentyfive + epsilon

        Assert.IsTrue(zero < zeroPlusEpsilon)

        Assert.IsTrue(twentyfive < twentyfivePlusEpsilon) ' <-- This is failing.
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `25.0 + Double.Epsilon` yields `25.0` even if `Double.Epsilon` is larger than zero. That is because `Double` is limited.

You find a more detailed explanation here:

[Why does adding double.epsilon to a value result in the same value, perfectly equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506477/why-does-adding-double-epsilon-to-a-value-result-in-the-same-value-perfectly-eq)

---

Apart from that, don't use [`Assert.AreSame`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243766.aspx) with value types. If you use `Assert.AreSame` with value types they are boxed. Instead use [`Assert.AreEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243413.aspx)

```
Assert.AreEqual(twentyfive, twentyfivePlusEpsilon)
```

Related: [What's the difference between Assert.AreNotEqual and Assert.AreNotSame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543263/whats-the-difference-between-assert-arenotequal-and-assert-arenotsame)

Comment: Good spot, I changed slightly the question to match my real question.

Comment: @user4388177: have a look at the answers of the question that i have linked.